# is there a way to group queries in graphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm trying to group graphQL queries to have a more organized response.

I want to make a query for allEmployees and get back something in the following format

GraphQL Query

```
{
    Employees:allEmployees{
        id
        firstName
        lastName    
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "data": {
        "Employees": [
            "new":[
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "firstName": "James",
                    "lastName": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "firstName": "Charles",
                    "lastName": "Tes"
                }
            ],
            "updated":[
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "lastName": "Test"
                },
            ],
            "deleted":[
                {
                    "id": "1",
                },
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked into a few options to get named sub-request( like new, updated and deleted) via aliases on fragments but that doesn't seem to be a thing. I've looked at unions, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Ideally I would love to query graphql like...

```
{
    Employees:{
        new: allEmployees(status:"new"){
            id
            firstName
            lastName    
        }

        updated: allEmployees(status:"updated"){
            id
            firstName
            lastName    
        }

        deleted: allEmployees(status:"deleted"){
            id
        }
}
```

but I don't think it is possible to pass a nested query like this.

Is there anyway to do something like this? I'm using graphql with ruby via the graphql-ruby gem.

please let me know if anyone needs more information?

Thanks

---

Edit

To clarify. We have multiple entities that will follow the new, updated, deleted pattern. Looking to try and get a response where the results are nested inside a parent name/alias (Employees, Users)

```
{
    "data": {
        "Employees": [
            "new":[...],
            "updated":[...],
            "deleted":[...],
        ],
        "Users": [
            "new":[...],
            "updated":[...],
            "deleted":[...],
        ],
         ...                   
}
```

That is why we would want to nest

Comment: just play with `/graphiQL` ? simply place one query below the other

Comment: @xadm thanks for the comment. I'm looking to group queries with a label. Please see edit above if you have a second.

Comment: If you need to do this for different entities, you'll need to define a `Type` for each of them. Once you have that, it's just a matter of grouping the records you query from the database into the respective label that you want.

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL definitely supports nested queries and multiple top-level queries, and graphql-ruby supports these just fine.

If your GraphQL schema looks like:

```
type Employee {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
enum Status { NEW, UPDATED, DELETED }
type Query {
  allEmployees(status: Status): [Employee!]!
}
```

then you could write a query

```
fragment EmployeeData on Employee { id firstName lastName }
query Everyone {
  new: allEmployees(status: NEW) { ... EmployeeData }
  updated: allEmployees(status: UPDATED) { ... EmployeeData }
  deleted: allEmployees(status: DELETED) { ... EmployeeData }
}
```

That wouldn't have quite the specific form you're looking for – there aren't good ways to add or remove arbitrary levels in your query, like adding an "Employees" label or removing layers from React-style connection records – but it can retrieve the data you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidMaze.  I've updated the question to further explain the format I'm looking for. Based on your answer tho, I don't think its possible to do what I'm looking for. Would I be able to make a type that resolves into the format i'm looking for, or would that break graphql conventions?

Comment: You could create a type structure that produced that exact response format, by adding query `Employees: EmployeeStatuses` and then making a type with the `new`, `updated`, and `deleted` fields.  It is a little less...GraphQLy though, and it feels like rewriting your API to match one specific client's expectations.